# What are the odds of getting offered a PhD position where I am the 2nd preferred candidate?

Tags: phd, interview, germany

I was just told that I am the 2nd preferred candidate for my most preferred PhD position for which I had an interview some time ago. The position has already been offered to the 1st preferred candidate but they are telling me that the final result is not known yet as the candidate has not yet accepted the offer.

Meanwhile, I have another option that I am being offered and I have to let them know as soon as possible whether I accept this position or not.

Now, the problem is that I strongly prefer the position where I am the 2nd preferred candidate. I would only accept the second position if I had no any other options. All of my interests, passion and skills are much closer to the position where I am the 2nd preferred candidate. I could also do the second position, but I am not really passionate to learn and do what this research group is doing.

I want to ask what are the "approximate odds" that I may get offered the position that I am very excited about? I know that no one can tell exactly, and there are so many reasons that can affect the process. However, I am mainly interested in knowing what the people (professors, PhD students etc.) can tell from their experience. Is it common (in academia) for the first candidate to reject the position that is offered to them? In other words, how often has somebody experienced/seen a 1st ranked candidate to reject the position they are offered.

**EDIT**: For the users who want to close this question because "it is opinion-based": I do not want to know subjective opinions, but rather the experiences of the people. I assume people who have been working in academia (or people who have applied for many PhD positions before) have seen this happen and I would like know how often.

Comment: It isn't a game of chance. The "odds" are >= 0.

Comment: The odds are low enough that the only sensible approach is to proceed with the assumption that you won't get your preferred position. (Also, in Germany you can quit quickly and easily during the probation period. You still could accept the first position if it this important to you. You might slightly burn a bridge but that could be worth it.)

Comment: How could we possibly know the odds that that other person declines the position?

Comment: In response to the edit -- I was in academia for 10 years and recently left. I have seen a lot of situations like this. My experience is that if you tried to come up with a posterior distribution from the observed data that marginalized over all relevant sources of uncertainty, you would get a uniform distribution from 0 to 1. It's really impossible to say anything confident about what candidate 1 will do, you have to make your decision based on the facts you have. You have some leverage to try to buy yourself time and force school 1 to give you an answer so you have more facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally recommend framing this a different way, because (a) the odds, as you said, are impossible to calculate because it depends on too many unknowns (how much time did preferred candidate 1 get to decide, where is this school on their own list, what's the personality of this other person, ...), and (b) the possible downside of not getting any position at all seems to me to be such a negative consequence that you would not want to risk it even with a 99% chance. I have turned down otherwise good job offers when things could not be promised in writing because your livelihood is a serious thing you don't want to take risks with. On the other hand, if you genuinely would prefer taking another stab at reapplying than going to school 2, then I think this tells you that you probably don't want to go to school 2. In other words: I don't think you can compute meaningful odds, but even if you could I don't think they would help you make a decision.

So, with that in mind, I think the question you should be asking yourself, is how do you maximize your chances of getting into school 1, without losing the offer from school 2 (assuming you prefer going their to reapplying next year). There are a few tactics:

- You can email school 1 and say that you have received another offer (don't mention the name of school 2) that has a hard deadline, and you would like to know when they can give you more information. If you are an attractive candidate to school 1, this may cause them to pressure preferred candidate 1 to give them a response, because otherwise *they* risk not getting either one of their top two candidates.
- School 2 seems like they are trying to pressure you, especially telling you to give them a response "as soon as possible". You can try pushing back. You could say something like "I am very interested, but this is a very important decision and I have multiple offers, so I need time to compare them. When do you need my decision by?" Try to make them give you a firm date. Or, if they won't, you could say "Can I let you know by the end of the week?" -- try to buy yourself time, and see if you get push back. There's a risk here that they will think you aren't interested and move on, but I think it's a reasonable request and most places will either give you the time to make the decision, or will respond with a firm date where they need a decision.

If push comes to shove, and you can't get an answer out of school 1 before you need to respond to school 2, then I think you have to take school 1 out of the picture, because you don't have an offer from them. You have a firm offer from school 2. So, the question is, without making any comparisons to other schools, would you be successful and happy studying there? If so, take the offer. If you genuinely think you would not have a successful career there, then I think you should politely turn them down and hope you get another offer, or reapply.

It's very easy to give this advice, but this kind of situation is extremely complicated  and stressful. I very much sympathize with you and hope it works out well. My experience is that often there is a good outcome, even if it is not the one you expect and it is difficult to see how you will get there in the moment.